# Caught error still trigger `.catch` method for Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

### My problem

I have an asynchronous method `populate()` that tries to do something, and if it fails, catches the error and calls another asynchronous method `populateFromServer()` (which can fail too).
I call the first in a `Promise.all()` with a `catch` afterwards in case no attempt worked. However, `.all()` always trigger because of `populate()`, for some reason, although it should be caught.
Here is a simplified version of my code (typescript):

```
abstract class Database {
  public static async populate() {
    try {
      await populateFromLocalFile();
    } catch (err) {
      await this.populateFromServer();
    }
  }

  private static async populateFromServer() {
    await fetchFromServer();  // Might fail eg. if there is no internet
  }
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
Promise.all([
  ChildDB1.populate(),
  ChildDB2.populate(),
  ChildDB3.populate(),
])
.then(() => /* population worked (either local or distant) */)
.catch(() => /* no population attempt worked */)
```

My code seems to get caught after the `Promise.all` when `populate()` fails, even though I caught it and `populateFromServer()` worked perfectly fine (I checked with logs). Why? How can I fix that?

### What I tried

##### Returning `Promise.resolve()`

Someone suggested to return `Promise.resolve()` at the end of the catch block, but it doesn't fix the problem:

```
  public static async populate() {
    try {
      await populateFromLocalFile();
    } catch (err) {
      await this.populateFromServer();
      return Promise.resolve()
    }
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
```

##### Using `.then`

I also tried using the other way with `.then` but I still have that problem

```
abstract class Database {
  public static async populate() {
    await populateFromLocalFile()
      .then(() => doStuff())
      .catch(async () => {
          console.log('error happened here');
          await this.populateFromServer();
      });
  }

  private static async B() {
    await fetchFromServer();
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on what your saying, it should work.  I've a feeling `populateFromServer` is maybe not a Promise.

Comment: Does it work without `populateFromServer`? It throwing is the only reason I see that this can fail. https://replit.com/@knyzorg/FreshSickCallback#index.js

Comment: @Keith `populateFromServer` is an asynchronous function that returns either `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()`. I might lack a bit of experience with subtilities with asynchronous programming in JavaScript but I believe it's a correct way to do it?
@SlavaKnyazev I just tried without and it still fails. I really have no clue.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Biskweet/9hup368L/1/)

Comment: "*`populateFromServer()` worked perfectly fine*" - it probably didn't. So what's the error you are getting after the `Promise.all()`? Where does it come from? Log the errors that you caught, do some debugging.

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that even when I comment out `populateFromServer` the code still goes into the Promise catch. I'm updating the fiddle with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Biskweet Then it's clearly something else, in a part of the code that you didn't show us yet

Comment: @Bergi indeed it was another part of my code. Problem solved, and thank you for you help.

Comment: Using `Promise.resolve() or Promise.reject()` is very rarely the correct way to use promises in an `async` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `.then` method of my `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([
  ChildDB1.populate(),
  ChildDB2.populate(),
  ChildDB3.populate(),
])
.then(() => /* stuff */)  // <-- this is the part that failed silently
.catch(() => /* other stuff */)
```

Comment: Using [`.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) might help to avoid this - you'd get an unhandled rejection instead of (unexpectedly) getting success handler exceptions handled by the error handler.